# How does Xcode determine the IPA name?

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I'm trying to figure out why my CI process is naming the output IPA the way it is. I've been told it's Xcode that makes this determination, but I cannot find any information on *how*.

To be clear, an IPA is being produced and it is correct in every way except the file name. I can rename the file, but I want the CI to produce the correct name because currently it's quite confusing (it has the wrong environment name in the file).

How does Xcode decide what to call the IPA?

Comment: as far as I know IPA name is same as your workspace or xcproject

Answer (score 4, accepted):

IPA name is determined by Xcode (Till XCode 14) from

> Your Project -> Project Target Dependency -> General -> Identity -> Display Name

e.g.

[image]

Your IPA name is determined from `Display Name`.

Comment: Fantastic - thank you! This translates to the `CFBundleDisplayName` key in the `Info.plist`.

Comment: As of Xcode 15, this does not influence the ipa name in any way - check below answer instead

Comment: Thank you @steveSarsawa fair enough - I upvoted it again. After your edit, this is a legit answer.

Comment: @Marcel not an issue, I've answered when there's Xcode 10 was stable version and 11 betas were rolling out. Then no-one knows Xcode 14 will be last for this :)

Answer (score 1):

ipa name is determined by `Product Name` in Xcode `Build Settings` -> `Packaging` section. After changing the value of `Product Name`, you can see
that the product name under the `Products` folder has been changed too.
[image]
[image]

Comment: XCode 15, works, thank you

Answer (score -2):

IPA name is determined by Xcode from

which you can find in xcode project

Your Project -> Project Target Dependency -> General -> Identity -> Display Name

CFBundleDisplayName seach for this string in xcode project this is the display name of your iOS application

which you can modify any time